# Upload a replacement Alpha Testing APK on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, adt, aapt

I am using the new Google Play "ALPHA TESTING" tab in the Android Developer Console.

We have been successful with uploading 7 previous versions and distributing them to our Alpha testers using a Google+ Community.

This morning one of the team accidentally published version 7 to production instead of alpha. Unfortunate, but that is what happened.

Now when we try to upload version 8 or version 9 to the "ALPHA TESTING" tab in Android Developer Console, we see a strange error.

`Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will receive the APK with the higher version code.`

I am not sure how to work around this error. The Developer Console can provide a more detailed list, however, it does not appear to be helpful.

```
Previously active APKs supported more devices than those in the draft configuration. Some devices will not receive upgrades. 
Less Devices currently running version 8 are no longer supported by the current configuration. Such devices will not receive upgrades. 
API levels in range 4+ and 
Release track excluding all of [ALPHA] and 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN]
```

The manifests and AAPT badges are exactly the same and I cannot find anything in the change logs that would indicate there was a library, hardware requirement or other changes between version 7 and version 9.

The key event seems to be that version 7 was briefly put into production and then deactivated.

Has anyone run into this issue using Alpha Testing in Developer Console?

How did you work around it?

Comment: any update? Were you able to pubish the alpha? I made the same mistake of publishing it to production for a brief time

Comment: I was in contact with Google support. They were able to fix it, however by that time I had uploaded another package with a new package name. The old broken one is still in my Developer Console.

Comment: hey CoryTrese same problem here. How were u in contact with Google support? I cant find a way to send them mail. thnx

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an App store and not directly programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to fix this is to contact Google Play Developer Support.

A problem on their end I'm afraid.